# How can you achieve and maintain flow while pair programming?

Tags: pair-programming, flow

[Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28psychology%29) is a concept introduced by Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi; in short, it means to get into the "zone". You feel immersed in your task, focused; the task can be difficult but challenging at the same time. When people achieve flow their productivity shoots up. Programming requires a great deal of mental focus because we often need to juggle several things in our minds at once. Many like to work in a quiet environment where they can direct their full attention to the task. If they are interrupted, it may take several minutes or even hours to get back into flow.

I understand there's a practice in agile development and extreme programming called pair programming. It means you put the whole software development team in one room so that communication is seamless. You do write code with your pair because this way you get instant code reviews and fewer bugs get through.

I've always had problems achieving flow while doing pair programming because of constant interruptions. I'm thinking deep about an issue then all of sudden someone asks me a question from another pair. My train of thought is lost.

How can you achieve and maintain flow while pair programming?

Comment: I don't agree that other pairs can just interupt at any time.

Comment: An alternative to Flow is to identify and maintain position at the [Ballmer Peak](http://xkcd.com/323/). This may take a good amount of experimentation, time, and Scotch to achieve.

Comment: I'm distracted reading this question when I should be writing code.  If I was pair-programming with someone, I wouldn't have opened this question to read it, and would presumably be getting more done.

Answer (score 16):

**Edit:** Disclaimer - This is how I define "the zone":
*`A state of extreme focus, in which one is able to understand how many intricate details connect together, regardless of whether these do so elegantly (or simply) or not.`*

I try to avoid this state because, while I may produce correct code in the zone, I and other developers will have a hard time understanding it later on. To put it short: reading code that was written in the zone may often require the reader being in the zone. That constraint is my problem.

There's a lovely chapter on [The Clean Coder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137081073) where Uncle Bob persuasively explains why "getting into the zone" is a delusively bad idea.

Here's a possibly better alternative than "getting in the zone": think straight and consider calmly and professionally what you're doing. Communicate. Share thoughts with your partner(s). Identify the real problems. Discuss possible solutions. You might not feel supernaturely focused, but you're likely to make good decisions, and approachable designs.

If you and your pair-partner can discuss the problem without both of you being extremely focused, then chances are you've boiled the problem down to its simpler nature. That suggests you'll be able to understand it again whenever you need to.

**On the flip side...** If you just need some time alone to get your head straight (we all do sometimes), just take it. Get your thoughts together. Work the problem out in your head first.

But the thing is that if you do - don't use that time to write production code. Instead, play around with sample code and prototypes. Try to understand the problem, without thinking about solutions just yet. Once you get everything straight and written down, discuss it with your team and pair partner, or even the rubber duck on your desk. If you still can't articulate it, or they can't understand it, then refine your ideas. Once you've nailed all of that down - integrate all that thought and sample code into a real, working solution.

Comment: I'd upvote a million times if I could, professionals learn to work whether they are "in the zone" or not.  Professionals can work with peopleinterupting them to ask questions, with noise around them, and together with other people actually having conversations about how to do whatever task they are working on together. I'm not interested in working with prima donnas who have to have special working conditons to concentrate.

Comment: Indeed. In my opinion, this "zone" attraction epidemic leads to a lot of wrong intuitive decisions - which lead to some of the things I try to avoid the most when I work. You can see my [post](http://ymarcov.blogspot.com/2011/10/simple-ideas-explained.html) for more details, if you're interested.

Comment: @HLGEM - I don't think having access to a quite place to work when needed is too much to ask for.

Comment: @JeffO It depends on the nature of the job. In some jobs, it might just be too much to ask for. I guess some of us wouldn't fit in that kind of job, but that doesn't mean that because of that it can't exist.

Comment: @HLGEM: Of course a professional is supposed to have average productivity under average working conditions. But on the other hand it would be in the employer interest to let the same professional work in a very focussed way, because this can enormously increase productivity and quality.

Comment: "It seems to me that people treat "the zone" as if it were some magic quick fix for solving problems well, like a thinking hat.": No, more trivially, the zone is a state of concentration in which you are more productive because you are focussed on your task with no distractions. The zone does not make you almighty, it only makes you more productive.

Comment: @Giorgio I once had a colleague who claimed the following "I mess around a lot, not working, but when I sit to work, I work like 10 people". He was in the zone. He was indeed productive. I spent weeks debugging his code once he left.

Comment: @Yam Marcovic: This is not the kind of productivity I had in mind (producing more code of lower quality): if one uses isolation as an excuse to do what they want they are not being more productive. For me flow does not mean to mess around and then writing down a lot of code, but rather to systematically work on a specific task without being interrupted by other, unrelated tasks.

Comment: @Giorgio, being in the zone does not require quiet or good working conditions. They make it easier, yes. But once you learn to work in the other conditions, you can tune out pretty much anything. No one, in my experience though, is in the zone 100% of the time. And being the zone is a nice to have not a requirement. I have seen people who plug away faithfully way outperform people who only work if they are in the zone which only happens rarely for them. Private offices and no noise are extremely expensive, the increased productivity doesn't justify the cost in most larger organizations.

Comment: @HLGEM: I do not think it is a matter of expensive private offices but rather of work organization / planning. If the offices are too noisy, the alternative is to work from home (I have many colleagues who do that and it works pretty well). The fewer interruptions you have, the more you are in the zone. The productivity loss due to bad organization and poor planning causes a loss for the employer (they are getting less work done for their money), not for the employee.

Comment: @Giorgio I think you're missing my point. I'm saying developers should be able to get some time alone to think. It is not optimal, however, that they program in isolation from everybody and everything, unless it's part of the thinking process, and not something that's gonna get committed. If they do, this, in my personal experience at least, leads to reviews with many comments, or worse, non-reviewed and hard-to-maintain code. I'm not saying this is the only way it happens. I'm just saying that's how I've always seen it happen.

Comment: @Yam Marcovic: I agree with you. Also, being in the zone does not imply isolation. I think there is also the idea of an entire team being in the zone, i.e. of working each focused on a specific subtask, but without losing the coordination between different team members.

Comment: @HLGEM: I was also not suggesting that one should be in the "zone" all the time: for many tasks, a normal level of concentration is enough. Also, I agree with you that if someone refuses to work if they are not in the "zone" they are not professionals. On the other hand, there are tasks for which you need all the concentration you can get, especially if you want to get things right as soon as possible. I had to fix so many bugs again and again just because each time I had to do it quickly and did not have enough concentration to really understand what I was doing.

Comment: @Giorgio It seems that we agree on everything except the definition of being in the zone. :) But that's ok. For the record, I define it as a state of extreme focus, in which you are able to understand how many intricate details connect together, regardless of whether they do so elegantly (or simply) or not. I try to avoid this state because, while I *may* produce correct code, I and other developers will have a hard time understanding it later on. To put it short: reading code that was written in the zone may often require the reader being in the zone. That constraint is my problem.

Comment: @Giorgio I've edited the answer. It's less of a rant now, and more to the point. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Yam Marcovic: I think we do agree. As a measure against the problems you mention I think the following can help: (1) before "getting into the zone", discuss the overall architecture of what you are going to do with your colleagues (possibly write a few pages of documentation with diagrams and sketches of classes and control flow), (2) finished code includes doxygen or javadoc documentation of each public method, (3) follow the KISS principle: avoid classes / source files with more than 100-200 lines of code. This does not solve all problems, but it can help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8171/discussion-between-yam-marcovic-and-giorgio)

Comment: -1 this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Pair programming sometimes requires periods of isolation from your partner.

**Example**

You are working together on a particular class, and you realize that you need to write a method that requires deep thought on some complex logic, but otherwise returns a mundane result.  You work together on creating unit tests for that method, and defer the writing of that method to a period of time when you're working in isolation.  When the method is completed, you get back together as a pair and evaluate the results.

Comment: Why should the implementation not be made in pair programming?

Answer (score 5):

I've found there is a small class of problems for which pair programming works.  For example, if you are working on a cross platform product and the Winders guy has implemented a feature that requires OS specific code, he can help the Mac guy implement the same feature on the Mac code while the Mac guy drives.

However in my experience pair programming unusually results in a net loss of productivity.  It so often feels like we're paying two developers to do the job of one.

Yes, it reduces the horrifying possibility that a dev might take a stackexchange break during the workday.

IMHO it would be cheaper for those companies who want to police their devs to just pair every dev with a private security guard to stand behind the developer and hit the dev with a truncheon if he ever slows down or tries to peak at a non-essential web page.

Comment: The point of pair programming is not stopping each other from slacking off; that wouldn't even be effective.
The point is having code review in real time.

Comment: @Lev: Having a code review before committing is much more efficient: the review takes from a few minutes to half and hour, instead of an entire workday.

Comment: @Giorgio Not quite. For example, it can so happen that you make a bug, then waste time catching it, and only then get your code reviewed and commit. If you had pair programmed, your partner would have noticed the bug and saved the debugging time.

Comment: @Lev: "If you had pair programmed, your partner would have noticed the bug and saved the debugging time.": There is no guarantee that a bug is noticed either with pair programming or with code reviews. E.g., after six hours of pair programming one might be so tired that one easily overlooks bugs.

Comment: Obviously there is no guarantee, but it can help.

Comment: Downvote (revocation possible): you don't give details on your negative experiences. Further your pro-example is very narrow. It probably affects only 10% of the developers.

Answer (score 3):

As a developer attempting to get into the zone, you'll attempt to isolate yourself as best as you can to get comfortable and clear your mind. Why should pair programming be any different?

You and your partner should find a zone-inducing environment that works for you both. This will possibly require compromise on some things, but my main point is that the pair environment should be similar to the solo. Turn off the external world. The pair is programming together; other pairs (other co-workers in general) should not be interrupting (excepting critical, drop-what-you-are-doing problems).

Answer (score 0):

Flow is a great state to be in when you know the exact steps to solve a problem. i.e. few unknown unknowns. You sit in a quiet corner and hammer away the solution. However, most problems/stories/features are not very clear when you start programming them. There will always be a "gap" between the end state expected and how your brain has "planned" it. You learn a lot of things when you actually "do it". Your brain juggles

- Code Design
- Typing
- Learning new things about the domain and code

When I program alone, I struggle to balance these things. I tend to get into "rabbit holes" where my sunk cost fallacy prevents me from taking a step back and looking at the big picture and changing my design. It is also hard for me to talk to an imaginary rubber duck or a real one for that matter. I am after all in "flow".

When I am productively pair programming though, I get alternating periods of typing followed by periods of thinking and reflection. This is where a lot of hidden things reveal themselves and a different design may emerge. If I am going into a rabbit hole, my pairing partner can pull me out of it. Talking/explaining something to a real human being has this wonderful effect of making your thoughts clearer somehow. 
Sometimes, I do miss being in the "flow", but I think I contribute much more to my team when I pair program than when I program solo. After all programming != typing. Programming happens in the brain and better programming happens when two brains collaborate and criticise each other.